# Track file opening attempts from a process

Tags: linux

I am running an Ubuntu(10.04) box and I am attempting to understand an error in a program.

I don't have access to the source of this program, but I know it isn't working properly because it cannot find a particular file.

I was wondering if it would be possible to monitor what file are accessed(more specifically denied access) by a process. My first idea was to breakpoint on fopen, but I didn't have any success.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*strace* - trace system calls and signals

Example

```
strace -e trace=file firefox
```